# Riemann integration advice

Tags: real-analysis

Could anyone advise on this problem? Thank you

Let $f\in R[a,b], c\in \mathbb{R}$ and define $g:[a+c,b+c] \to \mathbb{R}$ by $g(y):=f(y-c)$. Then $g\in R[a+c,b+c]$ and $\int_{a+c}^{b+c} g = \int_{a}^{b}f$

My Proof:  Given $\epsilon>0$, let  $\dot P:=\left\{[x_{i-1},x_{i}], t_{i}\right\}^{n}_{i=1}$ be any tagged partition of $[a,b]$ where $\|\dot P\| < \delta =\epsilon$. Let $\dot Q: =\left\{[x_{i-1},x_{i}], t_{i}+c\right\}^{n}_{i=1}$ be a tagged partition of $[a+c,b+c]$. Then, $\|\dot Q\|=\|\dot P\| < \delta$ and $S(f,\dot P)=S(g,\dot Q)$. Hence, $|S(f,\dot P)-S(g,\dot Q)|< \epsilon$, whenever $\|\dot Q\|<\delta$.

But, how do I show  $|S(f,\dot P)-S(g,\dot Q)|< \epsilon$, for **EVERY** $\dot Q$ with $\|\dot Q\|<\delta$ ?

Comment: Do you already know how to do substitution in integrals?

Comment: Yes. But this question was given before Integration by substitution was introduced.

Comment: **Hint**: find a bijection between partitions of $[a,b]$ and partitions of $[a+c,b+c]$, such that both upper and lower Darboux sums of $f$ on the former and $g$ on the latter agree.